# Rails 3.2.1 missing instant variables on AJAX response; Ruby 1.9.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am having a strange problem. Whenever I do a AJAX request I get an error about the instance variables being "nil". It seems that the request does not get anything from the controller.

This has worked on other PC's, I am now on a new ubuntu install. Some settings might be wrong.

I go trough this js function.

```
jQuery.fn.mark_todo_done = function (){
  this.live('click', function() { 
    $('.spinning').show();
    var todo_id =  $(this).attr("id");

  $.getScript("/mark_todo_done/" + todo_id)
    })
};
```

it goes to this route
routes.rb

```
match "/mark_todo_done/:id" => "private#mark_todo_done", :as => :mark_todo_done
```

And this method in the

privatecontroller

```
def mark_todo_done
    @firm = current_user.firm
    @todo = Todo.find(params[:id])
    @project = @todo.project
    if @todo.completed == true
      @todo.completed = false
    else
      @todo.completed = true
    end
    @todo.update_attributes(params[:todo])
    @done_todos = @project.todos.where(["completed = ?", true]).includes(:user)
    @not_done_todos = @project.todos.where(["completed = ?", false]).includes(:user) 
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

I get this error message

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id):
    1: 
    2: $("#todo_<%= escape_javascript( @todo.id.to_s) %>").remove();
    3: <% if @todo.completed == true %>
    4: $("#done_tasks").append("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => @todo)) %>");
    5: 
  app/views/private/mark_todo_done.js.erb:2:in `_app_views_private_mark_todo_done_js_erb___267824823023937232_51228900'
```

I get similar errors on all AJAX requests. Any ideas?

I also have this in my application.js

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({ 
  'beforeSend': function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/javascript")}
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution

Get rid of a call to private in the privatecontroller

```
#private
def mark_todo_done
    @firm = current_user.firm
    @todo = Todo.find(params[:id])
    @project = @todo.project
    if @todo.completed == true
      @todo.completed = false
    else
      @todo.completed = true
    end
    @todo.update_attributes(params[:todo])
    @done_todos = @project.todos.where(["completed = ?", true]).includes(:user)
    @not_done_todos = @project.todos.where(["completed = ?", false]).includes(:user) 
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

Hope it helps somone...